# After Effects - Control orientation on shape layer line cap

Tags: animation, gif, adobe-after-effects

Is it possible to control the line cap orientation when using stroke on a shape layer path?

I have created a gif achieving what I want:

[image]

Notice how the second stroke is different from the first one. I achieved this by masking out the "cap" (end of the line). This is basically what I want, but I need to do it in a way so I can add round corners afterwards.

Comment: How are you doing the wave effect?

Comment: @Cai You can make it by using a longer wave path (in a shape layer), put stroke on it, then trim it with trim path. Then use offset (in trim path) to move the trimmed stroke along the path, and use positioning to reverse the movement). 

In my case I used  [Ouroboros](http://www.sandervandijk.tv/blog/ouroboros). Here is a reference where Ouroboros is used to [create waves](http://ouroborosstrokes.tumblr.com/post/94434425489/free-ae-project-because-many-people-have-been).